# protecting CD rom from creating its ISO

Tags: drm, iso

I have a cd-rom based application developed on Director, i want to protect it from creating its ISO images, is there any solution?

Please let me know.

Thank You all

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. If a sector (on your disc) can be read then it can be saved to a file too. Doing this with all the sectors you end up with an ISO image.

Disc-based copy protection solution often based on the fact that writable CDs and DVDs have a pre-written area (containing information about the raw disc itself). You can not copy data to these sectors, but the original disc contents can be read into a file with other meta information about the disc.